# Positioning text along svg path

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, path

I want to add text elements following arbitrary SVG pathes. Below is a very simple sample image for this.

[image: sample path]

The real pathes may be more complex, the sample above is just for illustration.

Currently I do the following using the jQuery SVG library:

```
var texts = svg.createText();
var textOutput = texts.string('').span(customText.content);
svg.textpath(textStyle, '#' + textPath.attr('id'), textOutput);
```

This is not really fitting though. I guess this is caused by that the pathes are not "lines", but geometric forms. So the text seems probably not positioned inside the path, but follows it's border instead.

Now I wonder how I could simplify this. Would it be recommendable to add additional lines just for leading the way?

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: draw an invisible line along the major ellipse axis and put the text on that.

Comment: Maybe this answer will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999281/can-text-be-added-to-an-svg-path  Not sure I understand what you're trying to do.  The answer there should apply to any path, whether a poly line or otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, I think I will go for the invisible line. Thank you!

Comment: Does your text actually need to follow a path.  If, as your sample suggests, you are just producing angled text, then you don't need to use a text path.

Comment: Yes, it needs to follow a path. The sample above is just a very simple one. Imagine arbitrary curves the text needs to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing an invisible line inside the area and using this for the text flow does work fine indeed.